# Icon font in Rails App not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, icons, font-face

I am trying to include a custom font in my rails app as an icon font. (I'm using font-awesome)

The fonts are loading but the preview is completely incorrect: http://cl.ly/image/3x0g3X3k3X3S. (I think this means the asset-path is correct.)

You can also see here in the network view that the fonts appear to be coming in:
http://cl.ly/image/0y0R171S0l3L

In the HTML - when I try a  I can see all the correct CSS properties that should apply but the icon renders as a empty square which I believe is the missing character default.

Please let me know if I can provide more information. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I've also been struggling on those lines and have the following that works

- In assets/fonts put fontawesome-webfont.eot, ttf, and woff files
- In your css file put the following code (substitute iconmoon for fontawesome

  ```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot');
  src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
      url('fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  ```

  }

  [data-icon]:before {
      font-family: 'icomoon';
      content: attr(data-icon);
      speak: none;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size:  16px;
      line-height: 16px;
      line-height: 1;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }

In your erb use the following, substitute xe04b for the image you want to use

```
<div class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe04b;"></div>
```

hope that helps?